# How to convert a t3.micro instance into t4g.micro with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

a few months ago I deployed my own webserver in a VPC with terraform using this guide https://medium.com/strategio/using-terraform-to-create-aws-vpc-ec2-and-rds-instances-c7f3aa416133 I removed the RDS later because I just needed a simple Wordpress site.

Since then I figured it cost me a lot, more than 10 euros a month, so my plan is to add another t4g.micro instance in a cheaper region using this terraform (the same backend) I have. And then configure the arm instance to have Wordpress lamp with the ansible (like I did with the x86) then copy the Worpdress files from x86 to arm.

What would be the best way to approach this (Copying/adding the entire stack in a different region with different names and different attributes (less storage and different instance type))? I only want to destroy the old stack after setting up the new environment.

I'm slightly puzzled with the "provider" section of the code. I need to reference the alias of the provider on each resource? Seems kind of redundant, no?

I looked into workspaces and modules but I'm not sure with which to go with? Is there a better solution than that?

Comment: If you want to have two instances running in two different regions, you have to tell terraform that. So that means you have to have an aliased provider if you want to keep both instances running. AFAIK, there is no other way to deploy resources in two different regions.

Comment: But is there a way to not reference a provider alias on each resource? Can't I have a separate tf file and somehow tell terraform to apply the alias provider on each Resources in that file. So that it looks cleaner? 

Like, if I am providing on a single region, I don't need a provider alias. But if I am deploying in 2 regions, now I need to set provider aliases in both set of resources. That's ridiculous.

Comment: No, you would have one provider which would have a default `"aws"` name and the second one which has an alias. It all depends what you want to achieve. You can copy and paste everything you have in a different directory and just change the region. The downside to that is duplicating code (i.e., violating the DRY principle) and having separate state files. You could as well move the code you have to a module and then invoke the module twice and pass in the region.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the terraform documentation if you were to update your ec2 instance in-place by editing the `instance_type` attribute it would result in downtime:

```
Updates to this field will trigger a stop/start of the EC2 instance
```

If you want zero downtime, my suggestion would be to create a second `aws_instance` terraform resource so that you will have two instances (old + new). Then depending on how you route traffic (e.g. route53 or load balancer) you could shift traffic from the old instance to new. Alternatively, if you have a way of manually verifying the new instance ip address is serving your website correctly, then you could delete the old `aws_instance` terraform resource and run a plan + apply to remove the old instance.

Comment: This really isn't the issue. It couldn't possibly work since t3.micro is x86 nad t4g.micro is arm. This is why I need to create another instance (t4g.micro) and I want it in an cheaper region.